# How to enable all checkboxes when items have binding to a ObserverableCollection<MyClass>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a listview with multiple checkboxes. The item source in my listview is a ObservableCollection of a class that stores some default data I need when the item is selected. My checkboxes have properties in the class, this part works good.

Question: How can I provide a shortcut to enable all the checkboxes for times they are all needed from one checkbox as seen below. The checkboxes all having bindings to the class in the ObservableCollection so I'm not sure how I can accomplish this. I can't just set them all in the class instance because it's just a model, does not raise events and I'm not sure if I can/should do that with MVVM. My viewmodel does not know about them outside of the MyItem Source property.

code example:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- When this one is checked I want to enable the rest, shortcut to enable everything -->
            <CheckBox Content="Enable All checkboxes" IsChecked="{Binding MyCheckBoxAllIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Check Box One" IsChecked="{Binding MyCheckBoxOneIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Check Box Two" IsChecked="{Binding MyCheckBoxTwoIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Check Box Three" IsChecked="{Binding MyCheckBoxThreeIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Check Box Four" IsChecked="{Binding MyCheckBoxFourIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


public class MyItem
{
    public bool MyCheckBoxAllIsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool MyCheckBoxOneIsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool MyCheckBoxTwoIsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool MyCheckBoxThreeIsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool MyCheckBoxFourIsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If having "check all" functionality does make sense from model point of view, then you can code it in the setter of `MyCheckBoxAllIsChecked` (though you **will** need `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it to work correctly in UI). But I think a method instead of property will make more sense in this case.

If you added `MyCheckBoxAllIsChecked` just for UI, then it's better to remove it altogether and instead create a command or method in ViewModel which will set all the bool properties of the Model. You can call in via `Command` binding on CheckBox using its value as a parameter or just use standard `Checked` and `Unchecked` event handlers to call VM (it's a UI interaction, so code behind is ok to use here).